# Как из байта D0 получился символ DCD0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть файл, в имени которого есть болтающийся без пары байт `\xd0`:

```
touch `echo -en 'test\xd0.txt'`
```

[image]

Когда я смотрю список файлов в каталоге через питон, он декодирует мне его в такую юникодную строку:

```
>>> os.listdir('.')
['test\udcd0.txt']
```

И через эту юникодную строку он позволяет мне работать с файлом:

```
>>> open('test\udcd0.txt', 'r').read()
''  # (логичный результат для пустого файла)
```

Но вот, например, печатать её уже не даёт:

```
>>> print('test\udcd0.txt')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd0' in position 4: surrogates not allowed
```

Вопрос: каким образом из `\xd0` получилось `\udcd0`? Есть ли где-то чётко описанный алгоритм или это просто деталь реализации CPython? Могу ли я сам кодировать и декодировать такие битые строки подобным образом?

---

Для сравнения, listdir в Python 2, в котором все строки по умолчанию байтовые, выдаёт мне `'test\xd0.txt'`, никак не коверкая хранящееся на ФС имя файла.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97053/discussion-on-question-by-andreymal----d0---dcd0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том что в разных местах разные умолчания для кодека. И это сделанно не просто так.

Тут нужно разобраться в природе символов.

> code points in the range U+DC00–U+DFFF (1,024 code points) are known as low-surrogate code points.

Эти символы не переводятся в UTF-8 никак, они не считаются символами вообще. Питон используя внутренний кодек при выводе на экран выдает на эту последовательность ошибку.

Файловый менеджер обрабатывает ошибку как положенно:

> insert a replacement character (�).

Самое интересное как одинокий символ перевелся. Из сишной `fstat` притон получает байты. Во внутренней реализации используется замена на сурогаты. Это происходит внутри сишного кода, где поведение кодека установленно так:

```
>>> b"\xd0".decode('utf-8',errors='surrogateescape')
'\udcd0'
```

Это сделанно для того чтоб при обращению к файлу по имени не терялись байты в имени изз преобразования кодировки.

Функция `print` же доработанна в соответствии со [поведением по умолчанию питона](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode):  `errors='strict'`

**Вы** должны определить что делать с несимволами.
Вывести текст без ошибок можно если добавить к кодеку опции `errors='replace'`

С python2 такое не повторяется потому что строки в питоне смотрите не юникодные. Нет перекодирования - нет проблем.

```
python 2 : "" === b""
python 3 : "" === u""
```

PS.

```
open(b'a\320a','r') # работает
open(b'a\xd0a','r') # работает
```

Comment: Загуглив surrogateescape, обнаружил целый [PEP 0383](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/) на эту тему)